# format text in richtextbox when using stream reader to read in file c#

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox that i am reading a text file into using a streamreader on button click
I have formatted the text file the way i want it to be displayed within the text file using paragraphs but when i add the text into the richtextbox the formatting disappears. 
Is there any way i can format the text into separate paragraphs when reading into the textbox from a text file?

Here is my code:

```
         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"F:\test.txt"))
          {
              bool content = false;
              while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (line.Contains("[7]"))
                {
                    content = true;
                    continue;

                }
                if (content == true)
                {

                    txtContent.AppendText(line.Replace("[7]", "").Replace("[/7]", ""));

                }
                if (line.Contains("[/7]"))
                {
                    content = false;
                    break;
                }


            }


        }
```

The [7] and [/7] refer to a tag i have added into my textfile so that the reader only reads inbetween these tags and displays only that chosen text inbetween

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it windows Phone or Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: @AnupSharma it is a windows form application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string returned by [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.  Thus you need to manually append it to your `RichTextBox` at the end of each line:

```
                txtContent.AppendText(line.Replace("[7]", "").Replace("[/7]", ""));
                txtContent.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```